# File exists but returns "The system cannot find file specified" when using UNC path

Tags: command-line, php, unc

I'm using PHP to check if a file exists and then get it's size.

The code worked great before but now that we're using a UNC path I can check that the path exists with `file(exists($filename))` but when I try running `exec("getsize" . $filename, $out);` it tries to run for about a minute and then it returns that "The system cannot find the file specified". The user running this is currently an admin, otherwise I would think it is a permissions issue, but I'm not sure what else could be the problem if it is finding the file with file_exists() but then the exec() fails.

Any help or points would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Code example:

```
<?php

$filename = "\\\\server\\share\\file_path_with_folders\\3019-74 (2).zip"; //Example file

if(file_exists($filename)){
    echo "File Exists: " . $filename . "\r\n";  
    // "File Exists: " . $filename" are getting echoed out, so it is succeeding
} else {
    echo "File doesn't exist: " . $filename  . "\r\n";
}

exec("getsize" . $filename, $out); //Runs command line command
//Getting "The system cannot find the file specified" error
echo "Out: " . $out[0] . "\r\n";
//Echos "Out: " and nothing else


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, run [Process Monitor.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

Seriously, though, you should monitor the process with your favourite file-access-monitoring utility.

I would have to hazard a guess, but the space in the filename may be causing your problem. You may need to surround `$filename` with a set of quotes when calling `getsize`.

When assembling a command to pass to exec(), you also need a space in between a command and the parameters for that command. (This script produces the equivalent of "getsizetest.txt" instead of "getsize test.txt")

You should really run these commands in an [interactive PHP shell](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) on your local machine, if possible.

Comment: I thought you had it with the quotes but I added surrounded $filename with double quotes and it didn't help. I'm not sure I'll be able to run that on the server, have to talk to the server guys, but I will definitely keep that in mind. Thanks @EKW!

Comment: @gv0000 Added a note about another bug I noticed this morning, and I highly suggest using the PHP interactive shell (which is what made me notice the other bug... if I'd followed my own advice to begin with...)